# Law of Demeter: Static property access

Tags: pmd, law-of-demeter

I have a line of code looking like this:

`String someString = "something";
if (Foo.SOME_CONSTANT_STRING.equals(someString))`

which results in a violation: "Potential violation of Law of Demeter (static property access)"

What is the suggested approach here?

*(Edit: I changed the code example)*

Comment: The Law of Demeter is pretty harsh. Following it by the book will not always make your life easier. Just saying.

Comment: @Sean I've noticed :-) But I'm stubborn... I'll bang my head a few more times before giving up.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with accessing static variables is that you are enforcing an external state to the class that is hard to test.
You should access it via a class variable such as:

```
private final Foo SOME_CONSTANT = Foo.SOME_CONSTANT_STRING;
public void doSomething(){
    String someString = "something";
    if (SOME_CONSTANT.equals(someString)){
        doTheWave();
    }
}
```

this, with a getter for SOME_CONSTANT, allows to test the "initial state" of the function more precisely.

Comment: It will be useful for testing purpose only or it has any other advantage as well. As we have to declare already declared constants again,writing extra code.

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
if ("hello".equals(Foo.SOME_CONSTANT_STRING))
```

because as far as PMD can know, `Hello` is for sure non `null` when `Foo.SOME_CONSTANT_STRING` might not be.

Also, check out [Wikipedia's page on Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) for a better understanding of it.

Comment: My example was a bit simplified. "hello" was a string variable I think

Comment: How can PMD think that `Foo.SOME_CONSTANT_STRING` could be `null` when it's `final` and set to a value?

I thank you for the reference but I'm not getting any wiser when it comes to the particular case of static property access. The only guess I have at this point is that if Foo was the calling class, I would not get this violation.

Comment: knowing that `Foo.SOME_CONSTANT_STRING` is a non `null` constant requires to resolve it. Which Findbugs might not do when its not in the current class. Looking at your question, I can not even tell it myself. I can assume it because its upper case and Foo seems to be a class, but I can't know it.

Comment: Let's say that you are right. How am I supposed to compare these two strings (one constant and one string variable) in a way that would not trigger violations? I don't want to move the constant to the invoking class , `Foo`, as it does not really belong there, but it seems to be the only way.

Comment: You mean to say that the variable should be first in the comparison?

Comment: Yes, but `"hello"` is really not a variable. It's a real constant from the language point of view.

Comment: Context and details is very important so I looked into my code to get the example as accurate as possible this time (without "simplification"):

`private boolean isXCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    return BleUuid.X_CHARACTERISTIC.equals(characteristic.getUuid());
}`

If I switch the two compared objects I get the method chain calls LOD violation instead.

Comment: How about: `private boolean isXCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) { return BleUuid.isX_CHARACTERISTIC(characteristic.getUuid()); }`? This means, creating a static method, which calls equal behind the scenes and not accessing the property at all...

Answer (score 0):

@Alix

This question was pretty old and there are many responses, but i think the correct answer was missing so am putting down my answer:

`SOME_CONSTANT_STRING` should be declared `final`

Additionally as mentioned by other users earlier, a `String.equals` call on a `null` String object can result in an NPE (Null Pointer Exception) and such situations are best avoided in applications so that there is no unpredictable behavior. A `null` argument to `String.equals` is completely acceptable. Hence if we want to use `String` constants (objects) to perform such comparisons, we should make those constants `final`.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I think a static property in another class ought to be treated as a global constant which is accessible and allowed by Law of Demeter. I don't see why it has to be defined as a class variable always except to get around the rule implementation in PMD and , perhaps, to avoid duplication of the double or triple dot accessors everywhere in the class. A static import might mitigate it in some cases.

https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/2179

I have raised the above issue for the same.